# Take screen shot of behind the window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, screenshot

I'm designing a WPF application which has the Aero glass effect and works in Windows 8 (where we can't leverage the actual Windows Aero using `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`).
To do so I need to take a snapshot of the region under my window without my application on it (and then apply blur effect on that image)! I'm using `Graphics.CopyFromScreen` but it captures the screen with my application included. I can't minimize the window, since this image is being redrawn every 100 msecs.
How can I achieve this functionality? (I'm using .NET 4.0)

Comment: redraw every 100ms with blur seems nearly unpractical approach. secondly to take a screenshot you need to hide your window for a while grab the screen and do paint, blur etc. to update you may draw when window is re-sized or location is changed.

Answer (score 1):

you  may take  win32 Api rout

[to caputre window](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20651/Capturing-Minimized-Window-A-Kid-s-Trick)

Answer (score 0):

If u really want to take a screenshot u HAVE to minimize or make it invisible. Additionally blurring every 100ms takes too much perfomance. Im sorry but if there is a solution it wont be lag free. Anyway good luck. May you take a look at this: http://brianlagunas.com/add-windows-8-aero-theme-support-to-your-wpf-custom-control/

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid!